# How to use patterens,age,age_stamp options in ansible find module

Tags: ansible

i want to find files in /var/tmp having specific pattetern "*_info" with last modified time greater than 200 seconds.

Here is my playbook

```
---
- name: find module
  hosts: myservers
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: find files in /var/tmp having specific pattetern _info with last modified time greater than 200 seconds
    find:
      paths: /var/tmp
      patterens: '*_info'
      age: 200
      age_stamp: mtime
      recurse: yes
      file_type: file
    register: out
  - name: to print the files
    debug:
      var: out.files
```

Getting below error.

```
PLAY [find module] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [find files in /var/tmp having specific pattetern _info with last modified time greater than 200 seconds] ***********
fatal: [ansc1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (find) module: patterens Supported parameters include: age, age_stamp, contains, depth, excludes, file_type, follow, get_checksum, hidden, paths, patterns, recurse, size, use_regex"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************
ansc1                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The find module parameter is `patterns`. You have a typed as `patterens`.